# Format a date and time in crystal report

Tags: database, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-formulas

My date is stored in a type date column in dd/mm/yyyy format. I want to print the date in yyyymmdd format.
When i used the following formula

```
tonumber(totext(db.colname,'YYYYMMDD'))
```

It gave me a "the string is non numeric" error when previewing the report.

Secondly,

My time is stored in a string column in 12 hour format. I want to display it as hh24miss format.

How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should NOT store dates/times as text in your database.
Use the apropriate datatype of your DBMS.

Otherwise you will very likely have further problems because of this.

When you've changed the datatype you could just drag&drop the database-field inside your report and use the formatting options of Crystal Reports to get the desired format.

If for any reason (I doubt there's a good one) you can't change the datatype, use the following formula.

```
ToText(Date({db.colname}), "yyyyMMdd")
```

This formula converts the string to a date and then formats the date with `yyyyMMdd` format.

Notice the uppercase `M` which is used for the month. Lowercase `m` is used for minutes.

Comment: For this formula i am getting the error a datetime is required here. My date column is of date type and time column is of string. I can't change the datatype as im not authorised to do so.

Comment: I first converted my data to datetime using ```cDateTime(colname)```. Then used this formula into your formula and it worked. Thanks !!!! :)

Comment: If the date column is of type date then there's no need to convert it to a date first. But that error does look like the format of the data is not `dd/MM/yyyy` in every row. For the time column you should be able to use something like `ToText(Time({db.timecol}), "HHmmss")`